# How to solve: passed to parser was not a valid GraphQL DocumentNode. Use 'graphql-tag' or another method to convert your operation into a document

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

Despite I have imported: `import {gql} from 'graphql-tag';`

[image]

I have this error while trying to get some data from a collection by using GraphQL/Apollo in React. Basically, I have this two queries:

```
export const FIND_TREEPARENT = gql`
query {
  reportingContexts {
        rootNode
    name
  }
}`

export const getTreeNodes = (parent) => gql`
 query {
  reportingTreeNodes(query:{parent: "${parent}"}) {
   name
   _id
   _partitionKey
    hasQuota
   nextRootNode
   parent
   referenceId
   title
   tree
 }
 }
`;
```

I need to get the information of the second query (**getTreeNodes**) based on the field rootNode of the query above (**FIND_TREEPARENT**). Basically **getTreeNodes** and **FIND_TREEPARENT** share the same rootNode/parent which is an id.

But I am a bit confused how to handle this queries both with functions or useEffect. For instance, i get the information of the query **FIND_TREEPARENT** as follow:

// FIND_TREEPARENT

```
  const { data: treeParent } = useQuery(FIND_TREEPARENT);
  console.log(FIND_TREEPARENT, 'tree parent');
```

then i have a useEffect where i map the info of the query in order to get the rootNode, only if the data are present and it runs all the time  the treeParent.reportingContexts change:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (treeParent) {
        treeParent.reportingContexts.map((context) => {
          return getTreeNodes(context.rootNode)
        })
      //  getTreeNodes(treeNodesFromQuery);
    }
  }, [treeParent.reportingContexts]);
```

But then the question is, how do i pass to the getTreeNodes query the rootNode i just got from the useEffect above? in order to get all the info from the query getTreeNodes? Because besides, the error i do believe i miss some logic in there

```
  const { data: treeNodesFromQuery } = useQuery(getTreeNodes);
  // const getTreeNodes = async (treeNodes) => {
  //   console.log(treeNodes, 'TREE');
  // };
```

Answer (score 0):

First, that's not doing string literal interpolation that you want.  Additionally, you're not using the apollo client for your tree nodes query.  You should use query variables, so something like `treeNodesFromQuery ({ variables: { parent: context.rootNode } });` instead of `return getTreeNodes...`

Your query will then need to look something more like

```
gql`
 query($parent: <whatever parent's type is>) {
  reportingTreeNodes(parent: $parent) {
   name
   _id
   _partitionKey
    hasQuota
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Possum, I follow the steps and now I have: useEffect(() => {
    treeParent.reportingContexts.map((context) => {
      return treeNodesFromQuery({ variables: { parent: context.rootNode } });
    });
  }, [templates]);

......... and .........


 export const getTreeNodes = gql`
 query ($parent: String){
  reportingTreeNodes(query:{parent: $parent}) {
   name
   _id
   _partitionKey
    hasQuota
   nextRootNode
   parent
   referenceId
   title
   tree
 }
 }
`;

-----and i get: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reportingContexts')

Comment: Even though if i console.log.   // FIND_TREEPARENT
  const { data: treeParent } = useQuery(FIND_TREEPARENT);
  console.log( treeParent.reportingContexts
  );
I can see the data so i suppose there must be something wrong in the useEffect, maybe sometimes the reportingContexts are not present. But How to do let it work only if they are present? i put also an if statement but I always get that the reportingContexts are undefined